# Create a service account for REST API in Azure Devops Service

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking for a way to create a service account to access the Azure Devops REST API.

The goal would be that this service account would be able to list all the projects.

For now the only solution I found was to create a new user, add it to an overall admin group and create a PAT for it.

Does anyone found another way of doing so ?

Thanks in advance

PS: we have a Azure Devops Service solution

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description and concern, please note that the service account in Azure DevOps Service is automatically created for you when you create an organization in Azure DevOps Services. It is used when clients communicate with the hosted service and can be viewed through the web portal administration page.

And it is not supported to manually create service Account in Azure DevOps Service.

For more information, you could refer to the doc: [Service account requirements - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/account-requirements?view=azure-devops-2022) & [Service accounts and dependencies - Azure DevOps Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/service-accounts-dependencies?view=azure-devops) .

Comment: The doc say " can be viewed through the web portal administration page." but I cannot see anything in the devops organization administration page. do you know where it is ?

Comment: By navigating to the Organization Settings -> Permissions -> Users, then you will see the automatically created service accounts corresponding to your Projects or your test agents.
By navigating to the Organization Settings -> Permissions -> Users, then you will see the automatically created service accounts corresponding to your Projects or your test agents.
For example: 
(1).Test Project Build Service (Service Account name)